# preg_match on part of a string to match another string

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5, preg-match

I need to do a comparison of two strings.  The first string looks like this:

```
http://my.app/admin/users/administrators/{id}/edit
```

The second string looks like this:

```
http://my.app/admin/users/administrators/1/edit
```

The `{id}` value represents a numeric character so, the strings above should match.  If I were to do compare this string instead, then it would not match:

```
http://my.app/admin/users/administrators/xxx/edit
```

How can I check if the strings match using PHP / Laravel?

Comment: This should be possible using basic regex matching. Just try to google first, then ask another question if you're still stuck.

Comment: **The {id} value represents a numeric character** Where is this rule defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead to achieve this

```
/(?<=administrators\/)\d+(?=\/edit)/
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/oY1kQ9/1)**

**PHP :**

```
$re = "/(?<=administrators\\/)\\d+(?=\\/edit)/"; 
$str = "http://my.app/admin/users/administrators/1/edit"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

**UPDATE:** Since the url contains having only one numeric combination so we can just use

```
/\d+/
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/oY1kQ9/2)**